# nodejs amqp can only receive message once

Tags: node.js, amqp, node-amqp

```
var amqp=require('amqp');
var conn=amqp.createConnection({/**/});

conn.on('ready',function() {
        console.log('Server Connected');
        conn.exchange('order',options={type:'topic'},function(exchange) {
                console.log('Exchange connected');
                conn.queue('order-consumer',function(queue) {
                        queue.bind(exchange,'');
                        console.log('Queue Connected');
                        queue.subscribe({ack:true},function(msg) {
                                //conn.end();
                                console.log(msg);
                        });
                });
        });
});
```

Notice that, `conn.end()` is commented out. After a lot of research, I still don't get it why is it needed here. Although it makes the magic, but the connection is ended everytime, and have to connect to the server again after every message.

Is this how AMQP designed? Or is this the problem with node-amqp implementation?

Answer (score 1):

As the [fine manual](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp#queuesubscribeoptions-listener) states:

> Setting the options argument to `{ ack: true }` (which defaults to `false`) will make it so that the AMQP server only delivers a single message at a time. When you want the next message, call `q.shift()`.

You're not calling `queue.shift()`:

```
queue.subscribe({ ack : true }, function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  queue.shift(); // <-- necessary
});
```